# How to leave user signed-in in facebook canvas app after having got an extended auth token?

Tags: facebook, canvas, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have gotten an extended auth token via PHP SDK 3.2.2.

```
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$access_token = $_SESSION["fb_".$cfg['app_id']."_access_token"];
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

I understand now I can make queries with this `$accessToken`

However, after 2 hours in canvas app, a window asking to `Play the game` pops up again.
I tried viewing `$facebook->getSignedRequest()` and it has a property `oauth_token` which is not equal to `$accessToken` but is older, of 2 hours length.

What steps should I take to keep users authorized and avoid popup window that asks if users want to play or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I'm not sure if you're using the Facebook JavaScript SDK in addition to using the PHP one but what you could do is use [`FB.getLoginStatus()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) periodically (say every 10 minutes) to keep the session alive on Facebook's end.

With games that we've created we came across this issue of timeouts and we found that doing a periodic ping of Facebook's API kept the user's session alive.

Comment: thanks. but, does it mean that if user will leave browser open without refreshing for 2 hours and come back he'll see a popup from facebook? is that normal?

Comment: Well this is the idea behind using a periodic interval; it can fire (at an interval you specify) when the user is on your Facebook canvas app. You can use the Javascript function `setInterval` to execute the request.

Comment: Yes, but I mean.. if they close browser then?

Comment: Then you can't control that unfortunately. It's up to Facebook to decide how long their sessions last. What you can do is make sure that you ask the user to grant the correct privileges to your app so that they're recognised as a returning user on both Facebook and your app.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I accept your answer, assuming I can save extended access token, save user into db, forget about facebook's sessions and cookies, rely on my own sessions, cookies, use facebook through its api for 60 days, and log out users from my system after 60 days minus ,, say 10 minutes :) tnx.

Comment: @AlexanderT. so were you able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Fix the bug in the `setExtendedAccessToken()` method within the `base_facebook.php` library.**

Find this code at the bottom of that method:

```
$this->destroySession();

$this->setPersistentData(
  'access_token', $response_params['access_token']
);
```

Add this line immediately following:

```
$this->accessToken = $response_params['access_token'];
```

Without that line, the access token is only stored in persistent data.  I think you tried to get it out of `Session[...]`, but it must still not be the correct token.

I had this exact same problem, where I couldn't get the extended token no matter what I did.  I added the above line, and then re-entered the app through the `apps.facebook.com` so it would generate a signed request.  Each of my test users properly picked this up and stored a token in session with an expiration date 60 days out.

Comment: By the way, Facebook has confirmed that this is indeed a bug:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/522398451204921